# get input attribute on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with mutiple inputs,each input has a button. is there anyway of getting the inputs value on button click, without hardcoding the inputs id?

.prev doesnt work as there is a span directly after input

example

js

```
$('button').click(function () {


var inputcontent = $(this).prev('input').attr('id');
console.log(inputcontent);

});
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="1">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button">Go!</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.parent()` here since `input` is the immediate previous sibling of parent `<span>` of the button:

```
var inputcontent = $(this).parent().prev().attr('id');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/47Y8B/)**

*Side note*: `id` started with number is invalid HTML4 markup. **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)**